# HTML5 & PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, html

I am assigned with creating an HTML page that accepts user input and then verifying the user input on a php script (upon clicking submit on the HTML page). Thus far, I am only trying to verify the first name variable of the HTML page onto the PHP page.

My issue is that the PHP page is not displaying the HTML variables, 'fname' I've looked around for a good solution but I am unable to find anything yet

I am using Aptana Studio 3 and I am running XAMPP. I have posted my HTML and PHP code below for you to view. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Assignment Four, HMTL/PHP Form
    </title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Begin the body code-->
    <h1>Assignment Four: HTML/PHP Form</h1>
    <p>Watch the following video, write a brief review and then click submit!</p>
    <!--Post the Scholartica Video-->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/d_2_8n86jA8" frameborder="0"
     allowfullscreen></iframe>

     <h3>Complete the following information:</h3>
     <form method = "post" action = "form.php">

        <p><label>First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "fname"></p>

        <p><label>Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname"></p>

        <p><label>Email:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "email"></p>

        <p><label>Phone:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "phone"
            placeholder = "(123) 456-7890"></p>
        <h3>Write a brief review about the video here</h3>
        <p><textarea rows = "4" cols="50" name = "review">What did you think?
        </textarea></p>

        <h3>Rate the quality of the video</h3>
        <select name = "Rating">
            <option>Poor</option>
            <option>Average</option>
            <option>Good</option>
            <option>Excellent</option>
        </select>

        <p><input type = "submit" name ="submit" value ="Register"></p>
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My PHP form looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Hi <?php echo $_POST["fname"];?>
    Thank you for finishing the survey
    Your responses have been recorded.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: The assignment is to take all of the user input from the HTML page and display it on the php page. My issue is that the PHP page is not displaying the HTML variables, 'fname'

I've looked around for a good solution but I am unable to find anything yet.

Comment: Is XAMPP running properly and you're sure PHP is loaded and working? Does [`phpinfo()`](http://us3.php.net/phpinfo) work as expected?

Comment: Also, ensure that the page is saved as a .php page, not .html.

Comment: XAMPP is running fine and I have my php page saved as a php file.

Comment: Could you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it seems to work. 
Entering name = "Bob" and clicking submit returns page with

> Hi Bob Thank you for finishing the survey Your responses have been recorded.

Make sure that:

1. Your second page that displays the result is called "form.php"
2. And also have both files in the same directory